# Selected ListView item column value

Tags: vb.net

I have created a listview,

[image]

and id like to be able to change the selected item values. I wonder if is possible to somehow access the "ID" string of the selected item.

I created an event to detect when the user selects an item and tried colID.Index.ToString but it just returns the actual column index. Anyone able to provide a syntax that will return the selected item ID?

```
Private Sub lvwCars_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvwCars.SelectedIndexChanged
currentCarIDString = colID.Index.ToString
end sub
```

Comment: `currentCarIDString = listView1.Items(0).SubItems(1).Text` : `listView1.Items(0).SubItems(1).Text = "100"`

Comment: This always returns 1 regardless of the selected item

Comment: Of course, the `0` index is hard-coded. Get the last selected index of the collection: `dim selectedIndex = listView1.SelectedIndices(listView1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1)`. As usual, check whether the `SelectedIndices.Count > 0` before accessing it. If you want to use the `ListView.FocusedItem.Index`, be aware that if a User selects more than one item, that value will be null (nothing).

Comment: I see, thanks for the info! fortunately for this specific assignment multi-select is turned off. Will keep this solution saved for the future tho. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's either going to be the item text or subitem text.

```
currentCarIDString = lvwCars.Items(colID.Index).Text
```

or

```
currentCarIDString = lvwCars.Items(colID.Index).SubItems(1).Text
```

Comment: @BrianNaranjo : A simple oversight by Ctznkane, he used C# syntax instead of VB.NET. I edited the answer to fix it.

Comment: @ParrishHusband : Unfortunately the `ListView` [doesn't have an indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.items?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ListView_Items). The property would've been marked as `Default` in that case.

Comment: @VisualVincent yeah looks like you're right, I usually see `Items` added unnecessarily in VB.NET but I got this one wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I found something that works for my specific case

```
ListView.FocusedItem.Index
```

since my ID is always going by up by one, this solution works perfect. However if anyone can offer a solution that can retrieve the actual value of a row of a column, that would be great.

Comment: You can use `ListView.FocusedItem.SubItems(1).Text` to retrieve the text in the selected item's ID column. See the documentation for the [`ListViewItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem) for more information about what you can get from a specific item.